# how to send data from socket server to aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send socket information to aspx page.eg. I have 80 clients connected to server. Server is doing some calculation based on the user input and if one of the condition is true, it will send the signal to all the connected clients. I'm the client. The other vendor is the server. Currently, my application is windows based, I want to change it to web based. So, When the server send the signal , I want to receive this signal from the web page.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where do you want to host the server? In your ASP.NET application or on your WinForms application? Who is going to be the client and server?

Comment: I have to do the socket client. currenly , i have the window based socket client. I want to change to web based. Socket server is done by other company.

Comment: "C# windows based socket client is listening their request". Clients don't listen, they connect to a server. A server is listening for incoming calls. Could you clarify what is what?

Other company is waiting for incoming socket connections?
You are waiting for incoming socket connections?

Comment: eg. I have 80 clients connected to server. Server is doing some calculation based on the user input and if one of the condition is true, it will send the signal to all the connected clients. I'm the client. The other vendor is the server. Currently, my application is windows based, I want to change it to web based. So, When the server send the signal , I want to receive this signal from the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, such two way communication is not quite achievable yet.

A web server cannot tell a browser to refresh the page. On the contrary the browser sends request to the web server to give it a new/updated page content.

In retrospect to achieve this you will want your page to have a javascript timer and send a request to either a WCF Ajax Enabled web service or a generic HttpHandler.

The service/Handler would read the data from a common source, say sql, xml what have you and return new html/update the page.

The issue described here is that you have race conditions. Some clients may update slower than others because of their connection.